# Lagrangian of a Josephson junction

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, electric-circuits, josephson-junction

The **lagrangian density** of the system, as given in [Squeezed-state generation using a Josephson parametric amplifier, B Yurke](https://doi.org/10.1364/JOSAB.4.001551), is given by

[image: Scheme of a Joephson Junction in paralell with an inductor and a capacitor attached to transmission lines]

$$ L(x) = \delta(x)\ \frac{\hbar}{2e} [I_c Cos(\phi)   + \phi \frac{\partial Q_j}{\partial t}] $$

$$+ \delta(x)[\frac{L}{2} (\frac{\partial Q_L}{\partial t})^2  - \frac{1}{2C}  (Q - Q_r - Q_J -Q_L)^2] $$

$$+ H_-(x)[\frac{L_0}{2} (\frac{\partial Q}{\partial t})^2  -  \frac{1}{2C_0}  (\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x})^2 ] + H_+(x)[\frac{L_r}{2} (\frac{\partial Q_r}{\partial t})^2  -  \frac{1}{2C_r}  (\frac{\partial Q_r}{\partial x})^2 ] $$

where the transmission lines have the parameters per unit length: Impedance $Z_0, Z_r$, capacitance $C_0, C_r$, and inductance $L_0, L_r$,

Charge across the capacitor is $ Q_C = Q - Q_r - Q_J -Q_L $,

$H_+(x) $ is the unit step function at zero, and
$H_-(x) = 1 - H_+(x) $.

Regaurding the Lagrangian of the Josephson junction, the first term is the energy of the josephson junctoin, that comes by taking the integral over power (P=VI) over time.
I could not find out the reason for the second term $\Big(\phi \frac{\partial Q_j}{\partial t}\Big)$ in the lagrangian for the Josephson junction. I tried to look at the DC bias model of JJ, which is the RSJ model [Koch et al, Quantum-Noise Theory for the Resistively Shunted Josephson Junction, 1980](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.45.2132) but I find it contradictory to the results of this paper. Eq 2.7, in the article by Yurke, says

$$\frac{\partial Q_j}{\partial t} = I_c Sin(\delta)$$

Hence, I dont think that the second term in lagrangian is because of the DC bias. Could somebody help me with the concept?